# How to overlay text on an image in a container--and keep the text in the container

Tags: html, css, image, background-image, overlay

I'm following the solution given in a bagillion places for how to overlay text on an image, using `relative` and `absolute`positioning. The problem is that the text with `position: absolute` pops out of its container and goes to the utmost `top`, `right`, etc.

I'd be happy to use a background image, but then I need tricks to get the container to match the size of the image, and I don't know of a way to make it fluid.

Seems like a pretty simple problem that folks are always looking for a solution to. Also the thing of overlaying text on an opaque image, and needing to use `:after`. Wish there were straightforward options for these situations.

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 10%;
}
.container img {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

#div1 .text {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#div2 .text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" class="container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/800x200" />
  <div class="text">
    <h3>Top Image</h3>
    <p>This text should be in the bottom right of the top image.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div><p>A bunch of miscellaneous text here.</p></div>

<div id="div2" class="container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/800x200" />
  <div class="text">
    <h3>Lower Image</h3>
    <p>This should be in the top left of the lower image.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `position:relative` on `.container` which is the correct container for `.text`. Note that the `img` is a sibling of `.text` and not its container.

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 10%;
  position: relative;
}
.container img {
  width: 100%;
}

#div1 .text {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#div2 .text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" class="container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/800x200" />
  <div class="text">
    <h3>Top Image</h3>
    <p>This text should be in the bottom right of the top image.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div><p>A bunch of miscellaneous text here.</p></div>

<div id="div2" class="container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/800x200" />
  <div class="text">
    <h3>Lower Image</h3>
    <p>This should be in the top left of the lower image.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation!

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure there is enough information. I am assuming that your containers are 800px wide and 200 px tall (I have used a min-height in case your container increases its height). If you could provide more specific information that would be great (there are more complicated ways using object-position property (etc) to make this a little bit "smarter".

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 200px;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 10%;
}

.container img {
  z-index: 500;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.container .text {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#div1 .text {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#div2 .text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```